# read a file from iPhone local storage

Tags: ios, iphone

**EDIT:** what I want is to create an app that can do the  following:
- the user put a file in the iPhone
- the user open my app and set the path of the file 
- the user send the app via  network using my app.

**The problem:**  How can I access the file in the iPhone local storage? Is there any other solution other than using local storage?

Comment: There is not public file system available on iOS, you can only access the file system for your apps sandbox. Also what have you done for research so far?

Comment: Yes, you have to get the path (StrPath) for app document directory & the append user's enter path with  this path to StrPath. Now you have to perform save operation on newly created path.

Comment: is there other solution other than using local storage?

Comment: You can store files up in cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way** to access the file system in iOS through your application unless you put a file in your application resources OR any other app provides public API to access its files like Photos app, Contacts etc.